# Ask for credential / account with facebook oath

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am developing a PWA that need to login with facebook. But, my users sometimes share their devices. (work phone / computer)

Unfortunately, using oauth authentication, when I do a login, if there is a user already logged with one account, other user can not change to other account. (without going to facebook)

Is there a way to force a oauth facebook login, to ask for the username and not just the password?

Comment: users are only allowed to have ONE account on facebook, so that is not really a valid use case, to be honest...

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication

Comment: @31piy reauthentication ask for password again, but do not allow to change the username.

Comment: @luschn I know that Facebook do not allow more than one account for user, but anyway I'll change my use case for another one that have the same issue.

Comment: then how about FB.logout? > https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/

Comment: No, there is no way to force that. If you are using the Login button plugin, you can make that show name and profile pic of the currently logged in user, but it doesn’t give a chance to switch to a different account in that place either. You can perform a logout via API - but only if you have a logged-in user (resp. an active user access token); plus, whether this logs the user out of your app only, or your app _and_ Facebook, depends on whether they were already logged in to Facebook before, or just logged in to it while logging in to your app.

Comment: @luschn Logout method will not always work (if user have logged in to Facebook from other site) , and I do not usually have the user access token.